# Extract first instance of character and digit mix using regex (R)

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a string that i would like to extract the first instance of the character/digit mix  - ie the first instance of the screen resolution below.

The string to match

```
scrn <- "  dimensions:    1280x800 pixels (338x211 millimeters)"
```

And i would like to get either a vector or list with entries `c(1280, 800)`

I can do this rather awkwardly with

```
strsplit(sapply(strsplit(scrn, " "), "[", 7),"x", scrn)
```

where i knew the `7` by reviewing the `strsplit` output.

But i am assuming there is a neat regular expressions way to do this

My attempt fwiw (which i would then need to split a couple of times)

```
gsub("[[:alpha:]]{2,}|(\\:)*(\\s) ", "", scrn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @zx81 hint of `(\\d+)x(\\d+)` this gets it done fairly neatly

```
scrn <- "  dimensions:    1280x800 pixels (338x211 millimeters)"
g <- regexec("(\\d+)x(\\d+)",  scrn)
unlist(regmatches( scrn, g ))[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
sub('scrn\\s*<-\\s*"\\s*dimensions:\\s*(\\d+)x(\\d+)', "c(\\1,\\2)", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

Output:

```
c(1280,800)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't work. I think the regex works slightly differently on R (also is it meant to be `scrn` instead of `subject` in your code?). But the `(\\d+)x(\\d+)` has given me a hint to get index positions of the string via `regexec("(\\d+)x(\\d+)",  scrn)`